# 'List object has no attribute' when querying 3 tables in database

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, querying

I'm running a query and filtering results on 3 tables.

I wrote the function below to perform this query, it looked like this:

```py
def bookshelf():
     your_user = db.session.query(User).filter_by(email=session['email']).first().uid
     your_books = db.session.query(user_book).filter_by(uid=your_user).all()
     name_books = db.session.query(Book).filter_by(bid=your_books.bid).all()
     return name_books
```

- The variable `your_user` gets from the table `user` the id of the user who is logged in;
- The variable `your_books` gets from the table `user_books` all the books added by the logged in user;
- The variable `name_books` should get from the table `books` all the data of the books filtered by the id of the books (`bid`).

The problem occurs when I try to filter using `your_books.bid`, the console returns:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'bid'

These are the tables cited above:

```py
user_book = db.Table('user_book',
                     db.Column('uid', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.uid'), primary_key=True),
                     db.Column('bid', db.Text, db.ForeignKey('book.bid'), primary_key=True),
                     db.Column('date_added', db.DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=db.func.now())
                     )


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    uid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False)
    hash = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=True)
    books = db.relationship('Book', secondary=user_book)


class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'book'

    bid = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    authors = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    thumbnail = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    users = db.relationship('User', secondary=user_book)
```

I also tried to do something like `your_books = db.session.query(user_book.bid)` but I got the same error message.

I also found this answer: [Sqlalchemy single query for multiple rows from one column in one table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34556826/7753089), but I couldn't apply it.

What am I missing?

Comment: While `your_user` actually gets a single record, and so you can access its fields, `your_books` gets a _list_ of records. You will need to either loop on the list items or, better, to make a query which joins `Book` and `user_book` on `bid` and filters by `user_book.uid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, and following some of the logic, you want to show the books, right? So instead of `query(User)`, use `query(Book)`. Then you can do the `.join()`as instructed in the comments.

```py
def bookshelf():
    your_user = db.session.query(User).filter_by(email=session['email']).first().uid
    your_books = db.session.query(Book).join(user_book).filter_by(uid=your_user).all()
    return your_books
```

If you have any questions, let me know and I'll clarify.

Comment: Exactly what I need!!! Also easy to understand. Thanks!